# Why my catalina.out is 500Mb?

Tags: tomcat, logging, catalina.out

I'm I noticed that my `catalina.out` in `/var/log/tomcat` is this big... why? How do I avoid this?
I don't want to disable logging, I'd like it to behave like RollingFileAppender in Log4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use logrotate on catalina.out.

Comment: In fact I found it somewhere and now it's ok